# Inserting records to MySQL with PHP Prepared PDO

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Hope this isn't just a typo, but I'm at my wits end. This code format and syntax works for another project of mine, but I just can't get anything.

Note 1: the variables are all populated. I checked with an echo.

Note 2: I checked to make sure all of the field names are the actual field names in MySQL table. All are varchar of at least 30 (which I didn't go over).

Note 3: The message is this: Error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username', 'userpassword', 'personname', 'familyname') VALUES ('hwilson':,'hwil' at line 1

Any help appreciated.

```
try {
    // THIS IS THE SECURE STUFF!
$sql = "INSERT INTO persons (username, userpassword, personname, familyname) VALUES (:username:,:userpassword,:personname,:familyname)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':username'=>$username,
                      ':userpassword'=>$userpassword,
                      ':personname'=>$personname,
                      ':familyname'=>$familyname));
}
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `:username:` to `:username`

Comment: Thanks guys. I had a hunch it was a typo, but couldn't see the damn thing.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be second colon after the username parameter place holder

Comment: Thanks! Feel like fool after staring at it for 20 minutes!